# networkx: set different alpha for each node?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I want to set a different alpha for each node. It's easy to set a different color for each node but alpha only excepts a single value. Anyone know how to do this?

(My goal is to have a color gradient from blue to red. If the value is below the midpoint it's blue and if above it's red. Alpha would set the gradient.)

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g,pos=pos,nodelist=nodelist, 
node_color=node_color, alpha=1.0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alpha` value will control transparency, not color.

If you are already supplying the `node_color` parameter, your nodes will be colored.

If you want them to go from blue to red based on those intensities, instead of alpha, use a [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).  E.g. `seismic` colormap goes from red to blue.

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos=pos, nodelist=nodelist, node_color=node_color, cmp='seismic')
```

### EDIT:

I stumbled across some odd behavior trying to dig deeper into this.

I would have thought that `networkx`'s plotting would behave like `matplotlib`'s `scatter` plot, and accept rgba colors, allowing you to specify particular colors and transparency.  But when I call `draw_networkx_nodes` with an array of 4-tuples to denote rgba colors, it sets all alpha values to 1.

```
rgba_colors = np.zeros((5,4))
rgba_colors[:,0] = np.linspace(1,0,5) #red
rgba_colors[:,2] = np.linspace(0,1,5) #blue
rgba_colors[:,3] = np.linspace(0.1,1,5) #alpha values

plt.scatter([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5], color=rgba_colors)
```

This plots some points with varying color and transparency.  But, if you try plotting with networkx, not only does the resulting plot have no transparency, the variable `rgba_colors` has actually been modified.

```
G = nx.complete_graph(5)
pos = {0: [0,0], 1: [1,1], 2: [2,2], 3: [2,1], 4: [2,3]}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, node_color=rgba_colors)
print(rgba_colors)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: alpha controls transparency and transparency affects how a color looks :)

Comment: Are you sure `rgba_colors` has been modified?  It doesn't appear to change for me.

Comment: @Joel Yes, it is modified.  I can prevent this by using a list of tuples instead of a 2D numpy array, but the resulting graph is the same.  However, I am using older versions of networkx (1.9.1) and matplotlib (1.4.2).